# createFromAsset function from RoomDatabase.Builder not recognized

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

I was following [Prepopulate your Room database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate#kotlin) guide but Android Studio doesn't recognize `createFromAsset` function. I step into RoomDatabase.java file (where is the RoomDatabase.Builder class) to see if the function was there and it wasn't, however [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#createFromAsset(java.lang.String)) says that functions `createFromAsset` are part of RoomDatabase.Builder.

This is my code:

```
@Database(entities = [ Crime::class ], version=1, exportSchema = true)
@TypeConverters(CrimeTypeConverters::class)
abstract class CrimeDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun crimeDao(): CrimeDao
}
```

...

```
private const val DATABASE_NAME = "crime-database"
```

...

```
private val database : CrimeDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context.applicationContext,
        CrimeDatabase::class.java,
        DATABASE_NAME
    ).createFromAsset("database/crime-database.db").build()
```

`createFromAsset` is in red color in Android Studio and error *'Unresolved reference: createFromAsset'* appears in compilation.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the version of room you are using?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari 2.1.0-alpha04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your room version to the latest:

```
dependencies {
  def room_version = "2.2.3"

  implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
  kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```

The [`createFromAsset()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#createFromAsset(java.lang.String)) Method in the `RoomDatabase.Builder` was added in version [2.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.2.0).